# Syncing iMessage in iCloud on iOS 11

Tags: icloud, ios

Can we sync iMessages with iCloud on iOS 11 Global Stable Update. Because I can't see any option to do that on iPhone 7 (recently updated to iOS 11.0 )

Answer (score 2):

Messages in the Cloud was [removed in iOS 11 beta 5](http://appleinsider.com/articles/17/08/07/fifth-betas-of-ios-11-macos-1013-high-sierra-tvos-11-and-watchos-4-available-to-developers) and wasn't reintroduced for the first release of iOS 11. It will be available [in a future update](http://appleinsider.com/articles/17/09/20/messages-in-icloud-not-implemented-at-present-coming-in-a-future-update-to-ios-11).

Comment: From what I've read it will be in the next release which is currently in beta.